# ClassCastException in Hibernate for QueryTranslatorFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm using Hibernate in a Maven project. The DBMS is MySQL. The libraries are imported into the pom as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.27</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now, when I try in Netbeans to run a simple HQL query (i.e. `from User`), I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate QueryTranslatorFactory: org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createQueryTranslatorFactory(SettingsFactory.java:436)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.QueryTranslatorFactory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createQueryTranslatorFactory(SettingsFactory.java:433)
    ... 7 more
```

The strangest thing is that I see a `ClassCastException` for `org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory`. I see from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/) that the correct configuration into the `hibernate.cfg.xml` for the `hibernate.query.factory_class` is:

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

Moreover, my `hibernate.cfg.xml` configuration file is:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datadb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <mapping resource="edu/project/entities/User.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="edu/project/entities/Code.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="edu/project/entities/Incident.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What's wrong?

PS: the MySQL server is online. Moreover I tried other queries, like `select u from User`.

Comment: is it possible that you have both hibernate 3.x and hibernate 4.x in your classpath?

Comment: Should I set the classpath variables when working in a Maven project? I did the insert queries with no problem. The `SessionFactory` does is job. The problem appears only for data retrieval.

Comment: After building your project with Maven, how do you execute it? via Maven? deploy to an app-server/Tomcat?

Comment: Actually I'm only testing the library in NetBeans, i.e. I'm using the basic run button to call the main of the target class

Comment: you will need to check the classpath Netbeans is using when running your project. Another option is by trying to check from Netbeans if there is a .jar file containing the QueryTranslatorFactory class

Comment: Also observe that the HQL query is runned via NetBeans by right clicking the hibernate.cfg.xml file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42788/discussion-between-drorb-and-mat-boy)